# How to provide interface implementation to maven dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven

I want to provide a custom interface implementation to a dependency defined in mavens pom.xml. **Case 1** shows the situation without a implementation. As you can see the pom.xml of my Spring Application defines the foo.jar dependency. foo.jar uses the DefaultConfiguration for the Configuration interface.

[image]

In **Case 2** somehwer in the Spring Application a SpecialConfiguration is specified. *What is a proper way to provide this SpecialConfiguration to foo.jar instead of DefaultConfiguration?*

[image]

Comment: It depends on how `foo.jar` uses `DefaultConfiguration`. Is it a bean?

Comment: @soon foo.jar has nothing to do with the spring context. It should stay clean if this is possible by any chance.

Comment: it will be hard without knowing lot of details. We defined library usually have system param to override DefaultConfiguration (assuming SpecialConfiguration is 100% compatible)

Comment: @Baski Ok. PF4J does pretty much what I want. As I already have OSGI and Spring I assumed there is a simpler way instead of bundling PF4J with my Application. Some simple kind of service discovery.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the default implementation to be a Spring bean only if the client didn't provide an implementation for.
If you use Spring Boot, you have very simple ways.
 For example you could use [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html).

The default implementation would be declared with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` :

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeanConfig{

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public Configuration configuration() {
       return new DefaultConfiguration();
   }

}
```

The client bean would be declared as any bean :

```
@Component
public class SpecialConfiguration implements Configuration {
...
}
```

In this way, `DefaultConfiguration` is instantiated only if no other `Configuration` beans were defined (and discovered by Spring).